# Which components of program state is shared across threads in a multi-threaded process?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

Which of the following components of program state is shared across threads in a multi-threaded process?

- Register values
- Heap Memory
- Global Variables
- Stack memory

---

My suggestion; Only global variables, global variables are allocated on the heap? So Heap memory and Global Variables. Is this correct?

Comment: global variables are in the static data segment of the program, not in the heap (if we are talking classic compiled languages like C)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Heap memory always.

Global variables depends on platform, usually they are shared.

Stack is thread-specific, as well as registers.

Comment: @data_jepp Yes, shared on linux. If you want to have thread-local "global" variables you can allocated thread-local storage using the pthread_* functions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language and the thread implementation. For example, I don't think that even C lets you directly access the CPU registers, so it's rather moot whether, say, pthreads shares registers (which, for the record, I am fairly certain it does not). Also in C, global variables are *not* in fact allocated on the heap, though they may be in other languages.

The stack is more complicated. In C/pthreads, each thread has its own stack, but in other languages and threading models, the situation could be far more complicated simply because the underlying stack models may not be so simple.

Comment: You can use inline assembly in C to access registers, but it starts to lose it's name of "Portable Assembly" then.

Answer (score 1):

stack : no

registers: no

heap: yes (if you have to choose y or n, the true answers is it depends)

globals: yes

Answer (score 1):

The Global values and heap memory are shared across a multithreaded process. Register values and stack memory are private to each thread.